# What is the phenomenon where a person inexplicably feels that a word is spelled wrong?

Tags: perception, language, language-processing

Sometimes, I get the inexplicable feeling, which also happens to be maddening, that the word **why** is spelled wrong. In my mind, for a few seconds at least, the spelling doesn't match with the word at all.

Other words are **while**, **when** etc. This is usually followed by a frantic search online or in a dictionary for the word's spelling, after which my mind truly believes that the spelling of the word is correct.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Have-you-ever-wondered-why-repeating-a-word-over-and-over-again-starts-sounding-weird

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation

Comment: A-are you sure you're ready? No-Not that I don't have comfidence in you but it's more important that you have confidence in you.
Do you have confidence in you? I-Is the word confidence starting to sound weird to you? A little.

Comment: Oh honey what kind a horrible mother am I? One that's smothering her son?! I-I-it's quite natural to feel guilty, bu-but I mean it's not too good to feel too guilty, but a little guilty is normal.
I mean you shouldn't feel guilty about not feeling guilty but Is the word guilty starting to sound weird to you? -A little.
-A little.

Comment: Wrong is spelled w r o n g.